# Two commands/events in one gridview (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, gridview

I'm a student and developing a website as a project in Visual Studio using C# and HTML5. My problem is that I need two command in one `GridView`. I tried to make two buttons and it didn't work.

This is the HTML code:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" RowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Play">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="play-sign.jpg" HeaderText="Play" Height="25" Width="25" CommandName="PLAY"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:ImageField ControlStyle-Height=" 100" ControlStyle-Width=" 100" DataImageUrlField="Picture" NullDisplayText="The picture doesnt exist" HeaderText="Photo">
                    <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                </asp:ImageField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Artist" HeaderText="Artist"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NameOfSong" HeaderText="Song"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Genre" HeaderText="Genre"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfRelease" HeaderText="Release Date"/>
                <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="Song" Visible="false"/>
                <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="picture" Visible="false" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add To Cart">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" CommandName="ATC"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns> 
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" Visible="False" />
        <!-- Audio Player HTML -->
        <audio id="audioplayer" typeof="audio/mp3" runat="server"  preload="metadata" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" visible="false" controlsList="nodownload"></audio>
    </asp:Panel>
```

and this is the C# code:

```
protected void play()
{
    audioplayer.Visible = true;
    string s = InfoDB.Getsong(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text, GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text);
    string p = InfoDB.GetPic(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text, GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text);
    Image1.ImageUrl = p;
    Image1.Visible = true;
    audioplayer.Attributes["src"] = s;
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.CommandName == "ATC")
    {
        Session["cart"] += GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        Session["cart"] += "_";
        Session["cart"] += GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        Session["cart"] += ";";
    }
    else if(e.CommandName=="PLAY")
    {
        play();
        var g = GridView1.GridLines;

    }
}
```

When i run the program it fails with an error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

My question is how i can fix it and how i can make an `Add to Cart` button and a `Play` button in this one `GridView`.